# Creating Array From Window.location.hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i am trying to create array from window.location.hash variable but i am failling.

**My code is:**

```
        $.each(window.location.hash.replace("#", "").split("&"), function (i, value) {
            value = value.split("=");

            var my_item = {value[0] : value[1]};
            form_data[i] = my_item; 
        });
        console.log(form_data);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to parse the hash or the search?

window.location.search returns the part after the ? and before the # which is the part that has the query string key/values.

Comment: @Andir - I don't think that's the case, because the OP removed the hash sign. Then again, apparently I assumed too much already.

Comment: I know that some implementations use the hash for things like history and whatnot, but I wanted to eliminate the possibility of a mistaken location identifier.

Comment: @Kobi +1 I removed hash sign to ready parse.

Comment: You didn't remove everything before `#`. The url will get read along, which I think is not what you want.

Comment: @syockit: Not true. "location.hash" only contains everything from the hash to the end of the URL. You're thinking of "location.href"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
your code is correct only error is

 $.each(window.location.hash.replace("#", "").split("&"), function (i, value) {
            value = value.split("=");
            var _formItem={};
            var my_item={};
            my_item[value[0]]= value[1]; 
            form_data[i] = my_item; 
        });
```

Answer (score 5):

Give this a try:

```
var hash = window.location.hash.slice(1);
var array = hash.split("&");

var values, form_data = {};

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    values = array[i].split("=");
    form_data[values[0]] = values[1];
}

console.log(form_data);
```

...Of course I suspect you may be wanting the search property, rather than hash, but I don't know your specific use case.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript doesn't support the following notation:

```
var my_item = {value[0] : value[1]};
```

Try this instead:

```
var my_item = {};
my_item[value[0]] = value[1];
```

This will create an array, where each element has a key and a value, for example:

```
[{name: jason}, {age: 23}, {location: pacific}] //array of single keys
```

Using a hash probably makes more scene in your case, so you can call `form_data['age']`, and won't have to look though the array:

initialize `form_data` to an object:

```
form_data = {};
```

Add keys directly to it:

```
form_data[value[0]] = value[1];
```

So the result is:

```
{name: jason, age: 23, location: pacific} //associative array with properties
```

Comment: That won't work either; my_item will be redeclared each time, so it will only contain the last key/value pair.

Comment: @no - nope. It is pushed to the `form_data` array, which is safe to assume defined before the loop.

Comment: how is that safe to assume? I assumed it was not declared.

Comment: Then it will not work. You must declare `form_data` as an array first (before the whole `$.each` loop) before you can use `form_data[i]` to add in data.

Answer (score 2):

**To get associative array from url hash:**

```
function readUrlHashParams() {
    var result = {};
    var hashParam = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    var params = hashParam.split("&");

    $.each(params, function (index, set) {
        var paramSet = set.split("=");
        if (typeof (paramSet[1]) !== "undefined") {
            result[paramSet[0]] = decodeURIComponent(paramSet[1]);
        } else {
            result[paramSet[0]] = "";
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

**Example URL**

http://localhost/Index.html#Param1=test1&Param2=Test2&Param3=

**Result**

```
var test = readUrlHashParams();
console.log(test);
```

Object {Param1: "test1", Param2: "Test2", Param3: ""}

Answer (score 0):

Undeclared `form_data` is not an object, so it can't have any properties, so `form_data[i] = ...` will fail. Run this script in a decent browser and the console should show you a message amounting to what I just said.

edit - no it won't because the bogus object literal syntax will trip it up first as Kobi mentions. Both issues should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample based on the following URL:

**http://www.someUrl.com/Index.htm#foo=bob&moo=alice**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>hash me long time</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Hello World!</p>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            var hash = window.location.hash.replace('#', '').split('&');
            var myArray = new Array();
            for (var x = 0; x < hash.length; x++) {
                var itemArray = hash[x].split('=');
                var item = new Object();
                item.key = itemArray[0];
                item.value = itemArray[1];
                myArray.push(item);
            }

            for (var x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++)
                console.log(myArray[x].key + ' is ' + myArray[x].value);

        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for code but i have to access variables like this: myArray["foo"] it this case i can't.

Comment: mTuran: Your original code, had it worked, wouldn't have done that either. `form_data`, assuming it was declared, would have numeric properties, just like Andrew's `myArray`. There was no indication that non-numeric properties were a prerequisite. And where is 'foo' supposed to come from anyway?

Comment: What is driving this decision to reference values via string index, as in myArray["foo"], is it Professor Smith?

Comment: because i have to have access variables individually

Comment: Professor Smith from Duke University, or UCB?

Answer (score 0):

Perfect Object.

```
location.hash = location.hash ? location.hash : "#!";
$.each((location.hash ? location.hash.split("#!") : [""])[1].split("&"), (function () {
 y = this.split("=");
 $hash[y[0]] = y[1];
}));
```

If you are not yet using #! you can change it to #

Comment: $hash comes back as undefined.